# SQL Error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended / Java

Tags: java, sql, list, arraylist

Right, This code below should do the following, Create an SQL statement that will find the free routeId by comparing two tables, a Booking table with the booked ID and a route table with ALL the ID's

This should return the ID of the free routes, which it does. But the tricky part I've tried is to insert this into a list so I can then randomize the list and return the random route.

The error is occurring near the end of this. Can anyone shed some light as to whats going wrong and how do i mend it?

```
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To select all free routes">
               try {
                   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   System.out.println(
                           " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   System.exit(1);
               }

           Connection conn3 = null;
           //new connection object
           Statement stmtFreeR = null;
           //new statemnt object
           ResultSet freeRoute = null;
           //new record set object
           try {
               conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.staff.ittralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                       "*", "*");
               stmtFreeR = conn3.createStatement();
               // create the statement for this connection
               //</editor-fold>

               freeRoute = stmtFreeR.executeQuery(
               "SELECT r.ROUTEID  FROM Route r LEFT JOIN Booking b "
                       + "ON r.ROUTEID=b.ROUTEID WHERE b.ROUTEID is null ");
               // get the results of select query and store in recordset object


               while (freeRoute.next()) {
                   // move to first/next record of recordset
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check: Select all free routes: " + freeRoute.getString(1));
                   //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the answer is " + fRoutes);
                   // output next record using string format
               }

               //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
               freeRoute.close();
               freeRoute = null;
               stmtFreeR.close();
               stmtFreeR = null;
               conn3.close();
               conn3 = null;

           } catch (SQLException e) {
               System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());

           } finally {
               if (freeRoute != null) {
                   try {
                       freeRoute.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }

               if (stmtFreeR != null) {
                   try {
                       stmtFreeR.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }

               if (conn3 != null) {
                   try {
                       conn3.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }
           }

           //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To randomize free routes">               
           if( freeRoute != null) {    
            List RouteX = new ArrayList();

            while (freeRoute.next()) {
                RouteX.add(freeRoute.getString(1));    
                Collections.shuffle(RouteX);    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Free routes list: " + RouteX);
            }
           }    
        else {    
            List RouteX = new ArrayList();    
//ERROR OCCURS HERE
            while (freeRoute.next()) {
                RouteX.add(freeRoute.getString (1));    
                Collections.shuffle (RouteX);    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Free routes list: " + RouteX);    
            }
        }
```

Comment: The ResultSet `freeRoute` is completely read inside the try-catch block and closed in the finally clause.  How can you be reading from it later in your code?  Please post the _actual_ code that is failing.

Comment: the code that is failing is included, i put a comment above the line where it occurs. but i understand what your saying, it cant read something that has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are trying to make a join, but in your where clause you check for the ID to be null. You can try change this where to: WHERE b.ROUTEID is not null

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, its still producing the same error after i altered the code